# Top "One percent" rating. Is the float number formatting correct? (1.00%)

Tags: feature-request, bug, information-display, personal-statistics

I noticed that if you are getting "top 1%" per year it is displaying as "1.00%" instead of "1%". It is right in case <1, such "0.98%", but it looks like somewhere on front/backend it is better to add a floating point only if *<1*, not *<=1*.

Current formatting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I think it is better to make *1%* without a dot and apply it only for *<1*.

Comment: I actually don't like that 2% _strips_ the decimal places though, on reflection, I do agree that 1% and 2% should be handled the same (even if we disagree about _how_). This kind of reminds me of all of the [pluralization bugs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bplurals%5D+is%3Abug+is%3Aquestion) of years past, where `1` of anything led to special handling.

Comment: I would guess that values of 1% and lower have been assigned the threshold where decimals become meaningful. Or perhaps 1% was the lowest possible value to assign it to? In any case: I vote for decimals on higher values as well.

Comment: I would vote for always displaying them with two significant figures.

Comment: On the other hand - does the additional SF/precision matter above 1%? We only 'really' have .01 and 0.05, and that's generally for the very top few users. Having no SF/decimal points feels neater to me *unless* you have top 2.5 or such

Comment: @AaronBertrand what benefit would we have from seeing ".00" added to all numbers? If there were cases where it won't be 00 then I'd agree with you, but that's not the case.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I only mean the `top n[.nn]%` numbers, not _all numbers_. We have things like `0.80%` and `0.28%` and it seems weird to have `1.00%` and `2%`. Maybe we just need one decimal place - I don't really think _the precision itself_ is important, just better consistency in presentation. And currently I _believe_ we don't have decimal places at top % >= 2 by choice (rounding). Why couldn't we have `0.8%` and `0.3%` and `2.1%` and `7.4%` - e.g. always one decimal place?

Comment: @Aaron sure, I also mean only the reputation league percentage. For less than 1% the precision is required, but when it's 1% and more, there's no precision anymore it's just showing round numbers anyway, that's my point. If you can find a user with 2.1% or 7.4% or any floating point percentage above 1% please link to that user, but I don't think that you'll find such a thing.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard Right, today we only show round numbers because we've explicitly set a rule somewhere that says > 1% or whatever, just round and _show_ a whole number. But we _could_ be showing an extra decimal place, if we wanted to, without arbitrary boundaries at 1%; it's not like we don't have the data or can't do the math.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I'd argue that on a site like ours some people _would_ care if they are `top 7.42%` or `top 7.4%` and not simply `top 7%`. Being consistent and a little more precise at the larger numbers actually feels neater to me than being super precise at low numbers and then rounding (or truncating?) at/above some threshold someone picked. But certainly the current behavior of _exactly_ 1% showing two decimal places, and 2% showing none, is inconsistent. If we're going to have all these formatting rules, should be `< 1%` and not `<= 1%`.

Answer (score 2):

> `... it is better to add a floating point only if <1, not <=1?`.

We have 15,745,778 users on Stack Overflow, source: https://sostats.github.io, (https://stackexchange.com/sites#users says 19 million).

The difference between 1% and 2% (IE: 1% of the users) is: 157,457.78, so 1/10 of 1% is 15,745.778 users, and 1/100th of a percent is still 1,575.

Using two decimal places is useful on our largest site, and for consistency this should continue on our smallest sites (where on our smallest site, with [1051 users](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126698/bioacoustics), a 0.01% difference is equal to more than just 10 users).

For example, the [top user on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (1,362,651 reputation) is rated at the top 0.01%, while the [178th top user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155423/shepmaster), with 345,835 reputation (a difference of 1,016,816 from 1st place), is still within the top 0.01%.

We should keep the current accuracy because we have many sites where it's useful, unexpectedly the smallest sites. On our largest site the accuracy isn't sufficient, but I wouldn't ask to have it increased either.

Comment: Agreed, the level of usefulness can vary by site, but I'll take a balance and consistency over tweaking per site (for the same reason I'd rather have balance and consistency in the precision itself whether it's near 1% or 7% or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

As a student of physics and engineering we were taught that you only display the number of digits for which you can claim accuracy. Thus, if you know that **exactly** 157 people out of **exactly** 10,000 did something then you can say 1.57%. But if it was somewhere between 150 and 160 you can only claim either 1.5% or 1.6% depending on how you are rounding. Similarly if it was 157 of **about** 10,000 then, again, you can't claim 3 digits of accuracy. The less certain you are about the accuracy of your input data, the less accuracy (significant digits) you can claim for any result you derive from them. Furthermore, such derivatives should, in general, be expressed with an error margin. For example, the Hubble constant is 72 km/s/Mpc +/- 2 km/s/Mpc.

If you say 1% then you are only claiming 1 digit of accuracy or +/-10%, if you say 1.00% then that's 3 digits or +/-0.1% accuracy. In the most general terms, 1% is somewhere between 0 % and 2% whilst 1.00% is somewhere between 0.99% and 1.01%

Comment: These values are all derived directly from a database query, although cached, so there might be 100 digits of accuracy here.

Comment: @Luuklag You've completely misunderstood my answer. I'm not discussing the specific data quoted, I'm pointing out the general rules for expressing scientific, engineering or statistical results. It's all to do with accuracy of data and significant digits. I once did a relatively crude physics experiment at school that just happened to give a result that matched the accepted international value to 4 digits, but would never claim more than 2 digits due to the methods used. BTW where are the accuracy figures for the database numbers?

Comment: Technically, sure. But how do you propose we should represent the user ranked 66,666th out of 1,000,000 users? Should it be any more or less accurate than the person who is 60,000th which divides nice and evenly? Frankly I’m not even sure I understand what your answer proposes - to leave it as is? To change it? If the latter, to change it how?

Comment: @AaronBertrand  Maybe you should think of the data in terms of groups of users. So you would group the 60,000th user in with the 66,666th and say they both fell into the 6th (60-70%) **decile**. It depends on how fine a distinction you need to draw between  various users. There is a relevent article here https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-percentile-3126238. IMHO there is no point in saying that X is the 66.666% user when saying they are in the 6th decile is adequate. Basically my answer is to use only sufficient digits that conveys the meaning and that can be justified on accuracy grounds.

Comment: Again, technically, sure. How many of our users do you think have ever even heard of the word decile?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now that's a question that is impossible to answer, but I reckon that most of the native English speakers who regularly answer questions on the English Language sites (ELL and EL&U) plus many of the contributors to the technical sites would know the word. However this is speculation and getting off topic and I've no desire to get into an argument.

Comment: It was rhetorical but not meant to be argumentative. Admittedly I don’t hang out on the English language sites but I’m not illiterate and I still can’t decipher exactly what you’re proposing. /shrug